# Javascript canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have some questions about a personal project that involves drawing on a canvas element using javascript. Is it possible to create a variable for a path? Do I access that variable with dot notation? And how can I rotate a path by a certain degree?

Comment: You can create an array of nodes (points) of path and draw a line to each node in array, if that's what you were asking. I really don't know what do you mean by accessing the variable with dot notation? And to rotate a path you should rotate each point and re-draw the path. Simple way to do so is by using [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 1):

**None of the paths you draw on Html Canvas are "remembered" so there's no way to rotate a path once it's drawn on the canvas.**

Instead, traditionally coded canvas animation works like this:

- Define a shape by putting its properties in an object
- Draw the shape on the canvas using that object as a template

And then to change the path's position / rotation:

- Clear the canvas
- Change the definitions of the path's position & rotation.
- Redraw the shape on the canvas using the changed object as a template.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var angle1Degree=Math.PI/180;

// define a shape by putting its properties in an object
var shape1={
  points:[{x:0,y:0},{x:50,y:0},{x:100,y:50},{x:0,y:50}],
  fillcolor:'skyblue',
  strokecolor:'lightgray',
  strokewidth:3,
  x:100,
  y:100,
  rotation:0,
}

animate();

function drawAll(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  draw(shape1);
}


function draw(t){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(t.x,t.y);
  ctx.rotate(t.rotation);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(t.points[0].x, t.points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<t.points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(t.points[i].x,t.points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=t.fillcolor;
  ctx.strokeStyle=t.strokecolor;
  ctx.lineWidth=t.strokewidth;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  drawAll();
  shape1.rotation+=angle1Degree;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<p>Rotating a path (shape1) by changing shape1.rotation</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```